# Oracle_CX Alter Table Drop Constraint

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g

i'm using Python 2.6 with Oracle_CX module to execute some query and I am unable to run an alter table where i drop a constraint query...
this is the query:

```
ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;
```

From SQL Developer it runs without a problem, but from Python it does not.

```
cur=connection.cursor();
query="ALTER TABLE "+str(tablename)+" DROP CONSTRAINT "+str(constraint)+";"
print query;
cur.execute(query);
```

and i get this error:

```
ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DBConnect.py", line 61, in <module>
    dropConstraints=Drop(connection,"USERS");
File "DBConnect.py", line 50, in Drop
    executeDropConstraints(connection, fk[0],fk[1])
File "DBConnect.py", line 57, in executeDropConstraints
    cur.execute(query);
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

The connection is not a problem. I don't know what is wrong...
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ; at the end was the problem...

```
ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS;
```

it's working fine without it.